# Chrome extension: Clicking notification opens multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, notifications

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {

    var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: msg.title,
        message: "Price: " + msg.price + "\nFinished ",
        iconUrl: "icon.png"
    };

    chrome.notifications.create(options);

    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://example.com/" + msg.link + "/a"});
    });

});
```

When I click on a notification for the first time, it opens a new tab. When I click on a notification for the second time, it opens two new tabs and so on. How can I  make the notification only open one tab?

I have taken a look at [Chrome extension: Creating a new tab after clicking on the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313371/chrome-extension-creating-a-new-tab-after-clicking-on-the-notification) and have tried doing the suggested (which looks like the below), but this then results in nothing happening when the notification is clicked.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {

    var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: msg.title,
        message: "Price: " + msg.price + "\nFinished ",
        iconUrl: "icon.png"
    };

    chrome.notifications.create(options);

});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://example.com/" + msg.link + "/a"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of the notificationId and to which link it should lead. For instance:

```
var linkMap = {};  //outside the listener function

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {

    var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: msg.title,
        message: "Price: " + msg.price + "\nFinished ",
        iconUrl: "icon.png"
    };

    chrome.notifications.create(options, function (notifId){
        linkMap[notifId] = msg.link;
    });

});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notifId) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://example.com/" + linkMap[notifId] + "/a"});  //use it here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now only one notification opens which is great, but the link doesn't seem to be changing and so some notifications go to the wrong url.

Comment: The link changes when a message is received. If you post the rest of the code, I could help further.

Comment: Do you have an email or something so it would be easier for me to send you the code? Also I've noticed that if I include `currentLink;` in the `message:` it changes, but in the link that any notification opens, they all link to the last notification. If it helps, multiple notifications appear at once.

Comment: I think that the problem is that when 3 notifications appear at once, `currentLink` is updated each time. And so when the 1st notification is clicked, `currentLink` will link to the last notification (the 3rd in this case). If you understand what I mean.

Comment: I've just updated the code to keep track of the links in the various notifications.

Comment: Happy to help. Just keep in mind that creating many notifications at once can be overwhelming for the user experience.